# How can i join 2 sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

When using SP 2007 and needed to do a join i just write the tables to a sql table and then use sql to join the tables.
What i really need to do is quite simple. 
I have a master list and another list that users insert records too lets say a child list.
When a user opens up the master list and clicks on an item i insert a record including their usernames to the child list
All i want to show the users(based on login names) is the items they haven't read and what items.
In sql i could have done something like e.g

```
 Select * from master where not in(select from child where username ='blalal')
```

Any ideas.Not sure if to do it on the client or in the object model.
Sure CAMl doesn't have joins

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 is supporting CAML joins. You can look for this [example](http://sharepointfordeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/10/step-by-step-spquery-list-joins.html) and msdn article: [List Joins and Projections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539975.aspx)

Comment: IAfanasov thanks for that great sample.
Can i always adda where clause to that?